# Wrapping data in a cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to wrap a word in a cell. The `<td>` has a dedicated width e.g 50px, now i want to wrap the data inside that cell so that it doest get on the next line i.e:

```
Column 1
Some data
wrapped
```

Required:

```
Column 2
Some da..
```

I want to know if it is possible though javascript or CSS?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by the `text-overflow` property in CSS, when used in conjunction with some other style rules.

CSS:

```
.wrappeddata {
    width:          50px;
    white-space:    nowrap;
    overflow:       hidden;
    text-overflow:  ellipsis;
}
```

The `width: 50px` defines the width.

The `white-space: nowrap;` prevents it from wrapping.

The `overflow: hidden;` stops it being visible past the 50px limit.

The `text-overflow: ellipsis;` makes the cutoff become replaced with '...'

To use it, simply:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='wrappeddata'>A block of text that is too long</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to truncate the text programmatically or just cut it off at the exact width of the container? If you just want the text to cut off then you can use overflow:hidden on the containing element and white-space:nowrap on the tag surrounding the text.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS you can style your `td`

```
td{width:50px;white-space:nowrap;}​
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BksWz/1/) with two tables.

Comment: Also maybe [text-overflow ellipsis](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try to play for Text-overflow:ellipsis (on ie) and the overflow attribute (available in all browsers). You may find hard to do this purelly in css and js.

Getting 'dots' to be printed can be achieve client or server side. But you'll need to implement something to check if your text will be widther than 50px. If this condition is met you will have to shorter the text and add your dots.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr><td width="40" style="word-break:break-all"> YOur.........Longgggggggggggggggggg Text
</td></tr></table>
```